# swap rollover img for src img onclick

Tags: jquery, hover, swap, src, rollover

I'm wondering how to go about coding my images (with rollover/hover states) so that when they are clicked, the rollover state remains even when the cursor is not over the img itself.  And have the other .sibling `<img>`s that may have been clicked prior to revert back to their non-rollover states.  Here is the code I'm using:

jquery

```
$('img').hover(function(){
var e = $(this);
e.data('originalSrc', e.attr('src'));
e.attr('src', e.attr('data-rollover'));
}, function(){
var e = $(this);
e.attr('src', e.data('originalSrc'));
});
```

html

```
<img id="button-all" src="images/button-all.png" data-rollover="images/button-all-rollover.png" />
<img id="button-adverts" src="images/button-adverts.png" data-rollover="images/button-adverts-rollover.png" />
<img id="button-musicvideos" src="images/button-musicvideos.png" data-rollover="images/button-musicvideos-rollover.png" />
<img id="button-films" src="images/button-films.png" data-rollover="images/button-films-rollover.png"/>
```

So right now when I hover (rollover) over the images they swap to the data-rollover srcs.  But when the images are clicked (since they're buttons with jquery commands), I want the src of the img to swap with the data-rollover src so that when the cursor is no longer hovering over the image the data-rollover src state remains.  Along with this, I need any prior clicked images to revert back to their original (non data-rollover) states with their original src paths.

1) Rollover image, it shows the data-rollover state (unless it's already been clicked and therefore won't change when rolled over to the data-rollover state).

2) Click on image, it swaps the src to the data-rollover src

3) All other .sibling images will revert back to their original src state.

Hopefully this makes sense!  THANKS!

Comment: I also suppose since all my rollover images are named with a -rollover.png extension, if there is a script that calls just to add a -rollover.png extension on the img src, the data-rollover will be unnecessary.  But then the image needs to stay while the .sibling images go back to non -rollover.png states.